# Double free in C without error

Tags: c, memory-management, free

I have a very large code with malloc's, free's, loop's etc. Sometimes, takes to long for me to figure out where is the problem since I receive the error in one part of the program, but what is really causing the problem is something far away in code. Most of the problems is caused by double free that I hadn't noticed. But some of them works fine for a time and then it crashes.

So, consider an example that works most of times:

```
int main() {

    char *x = (char*) malloc(10);
    char *y = (char*) malloc(10);

    free(x);
    free(y);

    x = (char*) malloc(10);
    free(y); // Am I lucky?

    return 0;

}
```

Why do I don't receive an error when running the second `free(y)`? I checked that the pointer of `x` after the second `malloc` is equal to the previous allocated address of `y`. It's not always that it works. Sometimes it crashes.

So, my question is: Is there any way to force the error when trying to do a double free?

Thanks!

Comment: On Linux, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: so, you are looking for a flag you can set in your compiler to throw a warning / error for a double free?

Comment: Nope, you are unlucky. Lucky would be a runtime error that would allow you to fix the problem. Unlucky is that the code appears to work. Sod's law says it fails when demonstrating to your most important client.

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of another question, but I don't believe its a duplicate of the cited question. Look at the question: *"Is there any way to force the error when trying to do a double free"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the free(), set the pointer to `null` to avoid "freeing" the same address.

Free() does not change the value of the pointer, thus, the address could be reused by the program to alloc new blocks.

Free(null) does nothing and will not break your code.

Comment: Won't wok with pointer aliases (e.g. 2 different pointer variables holding the same address)

Comment: Wow! That worked like a charmm. Perhaps it's a good programming practice setting the pointer to `NULL` after every free. Thus, I can avoid the error everytime, which is better than force the error :)

Comment: This technique might solve some problems, but it might actually hide problems (for example, you might still be not freeing something that you should be freeing).

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, in the case where it doesn't crash, `x` and `y` point to the same block. This is because `malloc` is giving you the block that was just freed. `free` has no idea what pointer you are using. All it cares about is what it is pointing to.

My suggestion is, after you free the memory a pointer points to, clear it (set it to NULL). This way, you no longer have a dangling pointer. In other words, change

```
free(x);
```

to

```
free(x);
x = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

A debug heap would probably catch most double-free problems right away.

With Microsoft's compiler you get a debug heap by default with a build that uses the debug runtime.

As Basile Starynkevitch mentions in a comment, you can use a tool like valgrind on Linux to detect these problems, but if you want something simpler to start out with, you can enable a debug heap using the `MALLOC_CHECK_` environment variable.  Something like:

```
MALLOC_CHECK_=1 ./myprog
```

or run the program under the gdb debugger which will enable heap checking by default.

Note that the specific bug in your program (assuming that the third call to `malloc()` returns the pointer just freed) wouldn't be detected by the `MALLOC_CHECK_` setting.  To fix a problem such as that, I suggest that instead of setting freed pointers to 0 (or `NULL`) that you set them to a known bad sentinel value:

```
#define INVALID_PTR ((void*) -1)

// ...

free(y);
y = INVALID_PTR;
```

This would make it so instead of hiding the fact that you're double freeing `y`, your program will "fast fail" on that bug.

Answer (score 0):

Always make it a habit of declaring pointer variables like this:

```
int* foo = NULL;
```

Then you can allocated the pointer and do whatever you want and then when it comes to freeing:

```
if (foo != NULL) free(foo);
foo = NULL;
```

This way you will avoid a lot of troubles later on.

Comment: freeing NULL is harmless, so you don't need the `if`.